# Switching images in a div upon hovering on a text using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

we have been given an assignment to make a div with a background image and couple of titles underneath and when you hover over a title it changes the background picture in the div ("thumbnail"). I am really new to jQuery and have no idea how to approach this. I tried the following code but it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
                <title>Portfolio</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css">
</head>
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('ul a')
        .mouseover(function() {
            $('thumbnail').attr('src', this.getAttribute('data-image-src'));
        })
        .each(function() {
            new Image().src = this.getAttribute('data-image-src');
        });
}
    </script>



<body class="body">
    <!--Header-->
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="logoimg"><a href="land.html"><img src="logo.png" width="80px" width="auto"></a></div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="work.html">Work</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!--Main1-->
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="back1.jpg" width="auto" height="auto"></div>
    <ul class="headlines">
        <a href="#" class="mylink" data-image-src="back1.jpg" id="link1">link1</a>
        <a href="#" class="mylink" data-image-src="back2.jpg" id="link2">link2</a>
        <a href="#" class="mylink" id="link3" data-image-src="back3.jpg">link3</a>
        <a href="#" class="mylink" id="link4">link4</a>
    </ul>
    <!--Footer-->
    <footer class="footer">
        <p class="fotext">Copyright Vítek Linhart 2017. Don't steal my shit.</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Try write `$('.thumbnail img').attr()`, you set src into `div` not the `img` and use css selector.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the thing you're looking for. Not a tested code. You've missed to say that thumbnail is a class and also it can be a hover event from jquery (check api.jquery for examples)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('ul a').hover(function() {
            $('.thumbnail img').attr('src', $(this).data('imageSrc'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it out and it still doesn't switch images. I checked it out, and I don't quite get how to append the picture to the div, the examples didn't help me that much :/.

Comment: Btw did you switch imageSrc for data-image-src on purpose? Couldn't the mistake be there that the data-source doesnt load the image?

Comment: If you access data attribute in html from jquery you can access data-image-src in the fashion I have accessed (check jquery documentation).
You have a mistake in closing function you want to execute on jquery load. I've edited the answer, just replace your script block with the one I paste

Comment: To access data attribute, follow https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: Follow this js fiddle. I guess it'd help - https://jsfiddle.net/4ob48b23/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use hover event : https://api.jquery.com/hover/
See this example as well : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_hover

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code. I wanted to ask though, if there is a possibility to make it animated. When the pictures switch make a fade animation.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('a').on('mouseover', function() {
        var iSrc = $(this).attr('data-image-src');
        $('.thumbnail img').attr('src', iSrc);
      });

    });
  </script>
```